# Entity framework code first : Relation without foreign key genereated?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using Entity Framework with Code First.

I have a table "Translations" :
Id, Code_Iso, Text
Composite primary key : Id + Code_Iso

And a table "Role" with a field to translate :
Id, CreationDate, RoleNameTranslationId

In my RoleModel, I want to add a List to reference all translation with Id = Role>RoleNameTranslationId.

The problem is we couln't make a reference like that in entity because a foreign key with 1 field to a primary key with two fields is impossible.

So my question is :
Is it possible to have a reference in entity without foreign key ?

Comment: You can instead determine foreign key at table Translations to table Role as many to one and at this case RoleNameTranslationId will not have any sense, Translations table will have one new column(FK_Role_Id) and also you will not guarantee that only Translations with same id have reference to exactly one Role (but you can fix it with the help of trigger on table Translations), but at the end you will have List of Translations at Role POCO as you wanted.

Comment: But the table "Translations" is used by many tables, not only "Roles"